# Formatting/permanently mounting an nvme1n1 type drive on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ext4, fstab

I have an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 22.04), that I would like to add an additional 20 GB drive to. I used the AWS console to create a new 20GB drive, and attached to my instance.

When I do lsblk:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
..........
nvme0n1      259:0    0    25G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0  24.9G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p14 259:2    0     4M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p15 259:3    0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
nvme1n1      259:4    0    20G  0 disk
```

I did the following:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 nvme1n1
sudo mkdir /etc/logs
sudo mount -t auto /dev/nvme1n1 /etc/logs
```

sudo lsblk -f produces:

```
NAME         FSTYPE   FSVER LABEL           UUID  
.....                               
nvme0n1                                                                                         
├─nvme0n1p1  ext4     1.0   cloudimg-rootfs 767f2b75-d030-4999-951c-d4ab6b37f31f   
17.4G    28% /
├─nvme0n1p14                                                                                    
└─nvme0n1p15 vfat     FAT32 UEFI            83EA-FFE2                              
98.3M     6% /boot/efi
nvme1n1      ext4     1.0                   44fee3dc-d8f3-44a2-a5e5-81aef5e27b7b   18.5G     0% /etc/logs
```

The contents of /etc/fstab have not changed:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   discard,errors=remount-ro   0 1
LABEL=UEFI  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0 1
```

Does this mean that when if the EC2 instance is rebooted, the new driver will no longer be mounted? if so, how do I modify /etc/fstab to make it permanent?

Comment: Yes you have to add it to fstab or else it won't be mounted. I recommand adding it by uuid. Simply search for "etc fstab" on the web.